# Why JavaScript show expected ";" error sometimes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, charts

[image]
everthing seems to be correct why im getting this wierd error ? did i miss anything?

Comment: You don't need a `;` after `function (){ }`...

Comment: Your actual code should be posted here. From the image you posted it's impossible to say what the error is.

Comment: You are probably missing a `;` in the lines above the function

Comment: spelling of `function` is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

you have a typo, it should say: `function` and you have `funtion`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all ";" you don't need it Javascript.